# call stack corruption in win32 vs2010 null dereference, but not in x64

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I create a simple win32 console program with vs2010 and create a null dereference:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (*(int*)(NULL) == 5) {
        printf("foo");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this with `x64` configuration I get an "Unhandled Exception" and valid call stack in the debugger.  When I switch to `win32`, I still get an "Unhandled Exception", however, the stack is invalid.  I get the following:

```
ntdll.dll!770a15de()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!770a15de()    
ntdll.dll!7709014e()    
>msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(...)
ffffffff()
```

Any ideas what is going on here and how I can correct it?

Comment: Why are you trying to dereference a `NULL`?

Comment: Your project settings for win32|debug is not generating debug symbols or you are missing the 32 bit debug CRT on your target machine most likely. It's not call stack corruption it's lack of debug symbols to make it human readable via your debugger.

Comment: I am definitely generating debug symbols.  I'm a bit skeptical that it is missing 32bit debug CRT, because the demangler thinks it found a match with msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl.  And there is nothing further on the stack.  It should at least show me 'main'.

Comment: I get a decent enough stack trace for all four combinations of x86/x64 and Debug/Release.  Can you set a breakpoints on the first line of `_tmain()`?  If so , do you get a good stack trace at that point?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is lacking symbols for certain Windows libraries; This can make it misparse the stack in 32-bit runs. Turn on Tools\Options>Debugging>Native:'Load DLL exports'. It's probably useful to also load symbols for ntdll.dll (right-click on it in the Modules window). After those, the frame where the exception was raised is still sometimes missing, but at least you see the call stack up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with default "Win32 Debug" and I got a valid call stack. I'm using Windows SDK 7.1. You should check your project settings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (*(int*)(NULL) == 5) {
        printf("foo");
    }
    return 0;
}

test.exe!wmain(int argc, wchar_t**argv) Line 6
test.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line552 + 0x19 bytes
...

First-chance exception at 0x0003139e in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x0003139e in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```